# Exceed maximum character message not display if user enter more than 5 characters

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to check user's input of subject is an empty or exceed max character. If user not which should display: Required Information message. If user enter over 5 character and it should display Exceed Maximum Character.
I do not know why no exceed max character message display if user enter more than 5 characters right away on the code.

Here is HTML file

```
<form class="add-form"
    [formGroup]="addForm"
    novalidate>
    <div class="add-form__group">
        <label for="subject"
            class="add-form__label">
            Subject
        </label>
        <input class="add--form__input"
            [class.add-form__input--error]="(hasError('subject') || hasError('subject', 'maxlength'))"
            formControlName="subject"
            id="subject"
            name="subject"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter a Subject Line"/>

        <ng-container *ngIf="(hasError('subject') || hasError('subject', 'maxlength'))">
            <p class="add-form__error-label"
                *ngIf="addForm.get('subject').errors.required">
                Required Information
            </p>
            <p class="add-form__error-label"
                *ngIf="addForm.get('subject').errors.maxlength">
                Exceeds Maximum Character
            </p>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</form>
```

TS file

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
export class AddFormComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    /** On Init */
    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.initAddForm();
    }

    public addForm: FormGroup;
    /** Checks If Controller has Error */
    public hasError(controlName: string, error: string = 'required'): boolean {
        const controller: FormControl = this.addForm.get(controlName) as FormControl;
        return controller.hasError(error) && controller.touched;
    }

    private initAddForm(): void {
        this.addForm = this.fb.group({
            subject: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5)]],
        });
    }
}
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0):

I guess its because of the below line.

Before:

```
public hasError(controlName: string, error: string = 'required'): boolean {
    const controller: FormControl = this.addForm.get(controlName) as FormControl;
    return controller.hasError(error) && controller.touched;
}
```

In this code, touched is changed only after tab out, as an alternative use `pristine` which is updated during typing in the field itself.

```
  public hasError(controlName: string, error: string = 'required'): boolean {
    const controller: FormControl = this.addForm.get(
      controlName
    ) as FormControl;
    return controller.hasError(error) && !controller.pristine;
  }
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b3wyxd)

Comment: @justin Does this answer solve your issue?